# Allow users to use embedded HTML tags in custom blocks

Tags: 8, blocks, wysiwyg

I'm using CKEditor in Drupal 8 and the client wants to write HTML that contains embedded tags like so

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <div class="menu-toggle-icon"></div>
</button>
```

Unfortunately, Drupal ends up mangling the code to something like this

```
<button aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" data-toggle="collapse" type="button"></button>

<div class="menu-toggle-icon">&nbsp;</div>
<button aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" data-toggle="collapse" type="button"></button>
```

I think this is in an attempt to prevent XSS but I'm not totally sure.

Should I be able to allow the user to embed tags? If so, how could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The W3C specs (https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element) show that a button allows phrasing content (https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/content-models.html#phrasing-content), e.g. a `<span>` to be placed inside a `<button>`, but not a `<div>`, so your WYSIWYG editor is correctly rearranging the elements.

Perhaps you could rework your code to allow for a `<span>` to be used inside the `<button>` and style that instead.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried using `span`, but the editor totally removes it

Comment: Is it being removed by the WYSIWYG editor or the text filter being used in Drupal? Are you getting no contents of the button being output?

Comment: i think it's the wysiwyg

Comment: After playing around with this further, only an empty `<span>` is removed

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here. CKEditor will not allow for incorrect HTML as per [this](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/pull/39) GitHub pull request found in [this](https://ckeditor.com/old/forums/Support/Disable-HTML-correction) forum.

I.e.

```
<button>
  <div></div>
</button>
```

Will always be reformatted.